# Find the exact value of cot theta

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\theta$ is an acute angle with

$\sin (\theta)=\frac{17}{41}.$

find the exact value of $\cot (\theta)$

Comment: I'm completely lost. Brain seems to have gone into meltdown over this

Comment: OK. [This](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ttrig.html) diagram may help. Can you imagine a right triangle where one of the angles would have a sine of 17/41? What then would be the cotangent of the same angle? Hint: What is a simple way to assign the lengths of the sides of your imaginary triangle so that $\sin\theta = 17/41$?

Comment: MSE is not an online service

Comment: @GuyFsone Well... it definitely is an online service. It shouldn't be an online do-my-homework service though :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ .  Use this to get $\cos\theta$.

Then $\cot\theta =\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$...

Answer (score 0):

$$\cot \theta=\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{\frac{4\sqrt{87}}{41}}{\frac{17}{41}}=\frac{4\sqrt{87}}{17}$$

Comment: Is there a reason of downvote??

Comment: Most probably you serve the answer on a golden plate for a question of the type "I do not want to make any effort, can you solve this scholar question for me ?". I avoid answering these now, as anyway they get closed fast and ultimately have high chances to be removed as well. And I'm not the downvoter, I'm just explaining the reason.

Comment: +1 for EHE @zwim Sometimes people do lots of effort and dont get the correct answer they come here and ask their questions...and other people help as much as they can..On the other hand, the downvote gives false informations because some people may deduce the answer isnt correct when it is correct...Anyway..

Comment: @zwim So I did't put all details in my answering

Answer (score 0):

$$sin \theta=17/41 \implies $$

$$ cos \theta = \sqrt {1-sin^2 \theta }= 4\sqrt {87}/41\implies $$

$$cot\theta = \frac {cos \theta}{sin \theta} =  4\sqrt {87}/17 $$